# Surface format is B8G8R8A8_UNORM, but vkCmdClearColorImage takes float?

Tags: vulkan

I use `vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceFormatsKHR` to get supported image formats for the swapchain, and (on Linux+Nvidia, using SDL) I get `VK_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM` as the first option and I go ahead and create the swapchain with that format:

```
VkSwapchainCreateInfoKHR swapchain_info = {
    ...
    .imageFormat = format, /* taken from vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceFormatsKHR */
    ...
};
```

So far, it all makes sense. The image format used to draw on the screen is the usual 8-bits-per-channel BGRA.

As part of my learning process, I have so far arrived at setting up a lot of stuff but not yet the graphics pipeline<sup>1</sup>. So I am trying the only command I can use that doesn't need a pipeline: `vkCmdClearColorImage`<sup>2</sup>.

The `VkClearColorValue` used to define the clear color can take the color as `float`, `uint32_t` or `int32_t`, depending on the format of the image. I would have expected, based on the image format given to the swapchain, that I should give it `uint32_t` values, but that doesn't seem to be correct. I know because the screen color didn't change. I tried giving it `float`s and it works.

My question is, why does the clear color need to be specified in `float`s when the image format is `VK_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM`?

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Actually I have, but thought I would try out the simpler case of no pipeline first. I'm trying to incrementally use Vulkan (given its verbosity) particularly because I'm also writing [tutorials on it](https://github.com/ShabbyX/vktut) as I learn.</sub>

<sup>2</sup> <sub>Actually, it technically doesn't need a render pass, but I figured hey, I'm not using any pipeline stuff here, so let's try it without a pipeline and it worked.</sub>

---

My rendering loop is essentially the following:

- acquire image from swapchain
- create a command buffer with the following:

  - transition from `VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED` to `VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_GENERAL` (because I'm clearing the image outside a render pass)
  - clear the image
  - transition from `VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_GENERAL` to `VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_PRESENT_SRC_KHR`
- submit command buffer to queue (taking care of synchronization with swapchain with semaphores)
- submit for presentation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> My question is, why does the clear color need to be specified in floats when the image format is VK_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM?

Because the [normalized](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Normalized_Integer), scaled, or sRGB image formats are really just various forms of floating-point compression. A normalized integer is a way of storing floating-point values on the range [0, 1] or [-1, 1], but using a much smaller amount of data than even a 16-bit float. A scaled integer is a way of storing floating point values on the range [0, MAX] or [-MIN, MAX]. And sRGB is just a compressed way of storing linear color values on the range [0, 1], but in a gamma-corrected color space that puts precision in different places than the linear color values would suggest.

You see the same things with inputs to the vertex shader. A `vec4` input type can be fed by normalized formats just as well as by floating-point formats.

Comment: Say a color component is an 8-bit unsigned integer, so it has a range of [0, 255]. As you said, that's a representative of the range [0, 1]. That's perfectly fine. However, when you provide a value in that format, you would specify it for example as (127, 63, 127) rather than (0.5, 0.25, 0.5), although they really represent the same thing. I thought that B8G8R8A8 means that the colors are stored as 4 8-bit integers, but you are saying that's not the case? What's the point of calling it B8G8R8A8 then?

Comment: Actually I just noticed that there are also formats like `B8G8R8A8_UINT`. I guess the `UNORM` is then telling you that the format is in `float`.

Comment: I found the [explanation on normalized integers](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Normalized_Integer). Feel free to ignore the previous comments.

Comment: @Shahbaz: FYI: you can delete your comments with the X button that appears beside them when you hover your mouse over them.

Comment: I know. I left them there in case you had something interesting to say about them. Either way it's strange to me that there is actually a distinction between UNORM and UINT, given that they are the exact same bit pattern.

Comment: unorm a = 1.0 (255); unorm b = a*a (255); uint c = 255; uint d = c * c / 256 (254). Basically that is trying to tell multiplication implementation has to be a bit different for unorm than simple fixed point integer multiplication.

Comment: @PauliNieminen, two years later and a graphics programmer, so I definitely know the difference now. However, your example is really not useful as in `uint d = c * c / ...` you should really divide by `255`, that is the result of the two operations are the same (although the `unorm` version has the division implicit, which is a valid point)